# $geoNear aggregation ignoring maxDistance

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

The following query should return cities within a distance of lng and lat. The city collection has an **2dsphere** index on its gps field.

```
City.native(function(err, collection) {
    collection.aggregate([{
        $geoNear: {
            near: {
                type: 'Point',
                coordinates: [lng, lat]
            },
            distanceField: 'dist',
            limit: limit,
            maxDistance: distance,
            distanceMultiplier: 1,
            spherical: true
        }
    }], function(err, result) {
            return res.send(result);
        }
    });
});
```

My problem is that when I set distance to 0 the query still returns documents with e.g.

```
"dist": 27507.15237596358
```

But it shouldn't return anything because there is no city within a distance of 0. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

---

Query:

```
lat=51.9637151&lng=8.5610982&distance=1
```

returns a document with following position:

```
"gps": {
  "type": "Point",
  "coordinates": [
    8.906756,
    52.030319
  ]
},
"dist": 24824.18378549408
```

But maxDistance is set to 1.

---

Before I used aggregation in the code above I used this code and it worked:

```
City.native(function(err, collection) {
    collection.geoNear(lng, lat, {
        limit: limit,
        maxDistance: maxDistance / 6371, // in km
        distanceMultiplier: 6371, // converts radians to miles (use 6371 for km)
        spherical: true
}, function(err, result) {});
```

However when I changed to aggregation it stopped working.

Comment: *[para]"Setting to 0 should return no results..."* Why would you want to do that? Set it to anything but 0 and it will work as expected.

Comment: @NeilLunn even if I set it to 1 it returns all documents instead of zero documents

Comment: Cannot reproduce. [ 151.00211262702942, -33.81696995135973 ] is 8753 meters from [ 150.92094898223877, -33.77654333272719 ]. Any number lower than that does not select the document. But `0` of course does because you **never** query for a deliberate no result. Perhaps you should show some data, which is likely your problem here.

Comment: @NeilLunn have a look at my updated question.

Comment: Still cant replicate. You do actually have "maxDistance" and not "maxdistance" instead? And there is only one "2dsphere" index on this collection

Comment: @NeilLunn yes, only one 2dsphere index and maxDistance in camel case. I updated my question with more details.

Comment: What is this `.native()` function you are using? This seems to come from some type of "document mapper" where it is a means for getting the underlying collection object. I'm not familiar with anything that has this method to do so though. Possibly a source of your problem as the native driver by itself works as expected.

Comment: @NeilLunn exactly! I am using the node MVC framework sails.js which uses mongo-node (if you set so, it supports a lot of databases). While sails.js has its own object db abstraction called waterline I can use the native() method to get access to the mongo-node layer.

Comment: I would suggest here that `.native()` is not truly returning an actual collection object and is possibly doing some "filtering" of arguments on it's own. I know "waterline" is a bit funny like that as it tries to "abstract" and be all things to all databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with following query:

```
$geoNear: {
   near: {
      type: 'Point',
      coordinates: [lng, lat]
   },
   distanceField: 'dist',
   limit: limit,
   maxDistance: distance * 1000,
   distanceMultiplier: 1 / 1000,
   spherical: true
}
```

It seems that maxDistance accepts values as meters. So if I want it to accept KM I need to multiply it by 1000. To output distance as KM the distanceMultiplier has to be 1/1000.

Comment: Shouldn't distanceMultiplier be 6378 or radius of earth in Km?