# $geoNear - $maxDistance in mongodb aggregation not working

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, geospatial

I have the following query which return the results based on the longitude and latitude using "`2dsphere`" index of mongoDB find(),however when i use the same query in aggregation the `$maxDistance` is not working and always showing the same result.

```
db.travelLocationSearch.find({
    location: {
        $near: {
            $geometry: {
                type:  "Point",
                coordinates: [-3.7037901999999576, 40.4167754] // madrid, spain
            },
            $maxDistance: (60*1609.344) // miles to meters
       }
   }
}).count()
```

Result count on 60 miles - 147
on 200 miles - 170
on 500 miles - 671

However when i write same query using mongo aggregate

```
db.travelLocationSearch.aggregate([
{
    $geoNear: {
        near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -3.7037901999999576, 40.4167754 ] },
        distanceField: "dist.calculated",
        maxDistance: (100 * 1609.34), // miles to meter
        distanceMultiplier: 0.000621371, // meter to miles
        includeLocs: "dist.location",
        spherical: true
     }
   }
]).itcount()
```

Result count on 60 miles - 100
on 200 miles - 100
on 500 miles - 100
I also verify my query as explained here ([$geoNear aggregation ignoring maxDistance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25862801/geonear-aggregation-ignoring-maxdistance))
Below is my index

```
> db.travelLocationSearch1.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "zen.travelLocationSearch"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "location" : "2dsphere"
        },
        "name" : "location_2dsphere",
        "ns" : "zenbrisa.travelLocationSearch1",
        "2dsphereIndexVersion" : 3
   }
]
```

Please let me know the solution.My basic requirement is getting the results using given miles and lat, long and as user increases the miles result get longer and longer.

Answer (score 4):

I found that why i am getting the 100 result always, because by default the `$geoNear` returned 100 result that why i am seeing always 100 result, after increasing the limit the number are getting higher from 100 to 134 to more.
final query

```
db.travelLocationSearch.aggregate([
{
    $geoNear: {
        near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -3.7037901999999576, 40.4167754 ] },
        distanceField: "dist.calculated",
        maxDistance: (100 * 1609.34), // miles to meter
        distanceMultiplier: 0.000621371, // meter to miles
        includeLocs: "dist.location",
        spherical: true,
        num: 1000
    }
}]).itcount()
```

Result count: 409